# roslaunch: [ ] is neither a launch file in package [ ] nor is [ ] a launch file name

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use a package that someone else made. I placed it inside the src folder, then I ran catkin_make in the catkin_ws folder. The output was:

```
Base path: /home/gabriel/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/gabriel/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/gabriel/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/gabriel/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/gabriel/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/gabriel/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/gabriel/catkin_ws/build"
####
[ 25%] Built target odom_sim_2
[ 50%] [ 75%] Built target tb_tf_can2
[100%] Built target fake_localiza2
Built target sendToGoalManually2
```

Then I tried to launch one of the launch files included: roslaunch tb_tables tb_tables.launch and I get the following message:

```
[tb_tables.launch] is neither a launch file in package [tb_tables] nor is [tb_tables] a launch file name
```

Would anyone be kind enough to point out my mistakes? I just started with ROS and I am not sure why it ain't working :( Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

-Does the file actually exists?
Yes, the file is in the launch folder.

-Did you source the setup.bash file?
Do you mean source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash ? Yes, I did.

-What does rospack find tb_tables output?
[rospack] Error: stack/package tb_tables not found

After using `source /home/gabriel/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` I can find it with rospack find.

Now it works, Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143496/roslaunch:-%5B-%5D-is-neither-a-launch-file-in-package-%5B-%5D-nor-is-%5B-%5D-a-launch-file-name/) by [Elvish Champion](https://answers.ros.org/users/13736/elvish-champion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 165 on 2014-03-23

Post score: 16

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2014-07-31**:
Got the same problem but this didnt help still the same error.

**Comment by [alonzo98](https://answers.ros.org/users/33328/alonzo98/) on 2018-01-17**:
I've got the same problem for days but the answer is the same, could you tell me if you found the answer please?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-26**:
@alonzo98 why don't you ask a new question and reference this one? The question is almost four years old after all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Without any further information or poitners to the source of that package it is hard to tell what is going on. Does the file `tb_tables.launch` actually exist? Did you source the `setup.bash` file?

What does `rospack find tb_tables` output?

If that gives an error, try  executing `source /home/gabriel/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` and then try the roslaunch again.

Be sure to checkout the catkin tutorials, in particular this one, in order to know how to work with catkin and workspaces: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 29

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-23**:
If your problem is fixed, you can accept the answer so otheres see right away that this question is answered. Thanks.

**Comment by [schmellow](https://answers.ros.org/users/14001/schmellow/) on 2014-04-17**:
I've run into the same problem, but for some reason when I try to source the files, I get the message "no such file or directory," even though I've already clicked through every file in the path I'm using to make sure it's there. Is there any reason this would happen?

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-17**:
what is the `source` command you are trying to execute exactly?

**Comment by [ShehabAldeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/31455/shehabaldeen/) on 2017-09-04**:
this is very helpful answer I was facing the same problem and now it's solved
thank you

**Comment by [tentenkafaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/44268/tentenkafaa/) on 2019-07-25**:
It has solved the problem to execute "source". Thank you very much

**Comment by [har.kum_412](https://answers.ros.org/users/51075/har.kum_412/) on 2020-01-20**:
I am trying to use Hector slam
all my files are in the src folder and i even did the catkin_make in catkin_ws
sourced the files in devel/setup.bash
by following command - source /home/pi/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
and tried to run my command for launching the hector slam which is
roslaunch hector_slam_launch mapping_default.launch

still i get the error as

RLException: [mapping_default.launch] is neither a launch file in package [hector_slam_launch] nor is [hector_slam_launch] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

**Comment by [aleena_infinitynbeyond](https://answers.ros.org/users/44647/aleena_infinitynbeyond/) on 2020-04-12**:
I am trying to launch jaco arm in  moveit using the command roslaunch j2n6s300_moveit_config j2n6s300_jaco_lfd.launch
but getting this error-
RLException: [j2n6s300_jaco_lfd.launch] is neither a launch file in package [j2n6s300_moveit_config] nor is [j2n6s300_moveit_config] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
akashleena@akashleena-Latitude-3490:~/catkin_ws/src/jaco_con

I have already done
source devel/setup.bash still getting the error. Please help

**Comment by [samia.choueiri](https://answers.ros.org/users/56545/samia.choueiri/) on 2020-07-25**:
i have a similar problem, can someone help?

https://answers.ros.org/question/357790/why-i-cant-run-my-gazebo-model-in-paused-mode/

**Comment by [dvogureckiy99](https://answers.ros.org/users/101502/dvogureckiy99/) on 2023-02-18**:
didn't work !

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the following answer, which solves this problem:

yp7y-stu commented on 13 Dec 2020 posted:

I had taken 1 day to solve this problem.

My mistake was that I didn't git under `~/catkin_ws/src`.

The correct build method is described below:

```
$ mkdir ~/catkin_ws
$ mkdir ~/catkin_ws/src
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
$ git clone https://github.com/slamtech/rplidar_ros
$ cd ~/catkin_ws
$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
$ sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0
$ catkin_make rplidarNode
$ source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
$ roslaunch rplidar_ros view_rplidar.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [Tricia279](https://answers.ros.org/users/60504/tricia279/) with karma: 15 on 2021-02-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1